# Unable to access cloud firestore in firebase due to permission issues

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a firebase project owner,
My DataBase rule read and write set to true, But I can't able to read and write in the cloudFireStore storage.SHA1 and SHA256 key also added to the googleservices.json file, Permission Denied exception occurs.

**Exception details**:

> W/Firestore(12435): (21.3.0) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(users/null/info) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
> I/System.out(12435): com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.

**Database rules code**:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {

// This rule allows anyone on the internet to view, edit, and delete
// all data in your Firestore database. It is useful for getting
// started, but it is configured to expire after 30 days because it
// leaves your app open to attackers. At that time, all client
// requests to your Firestore database will be denied.
//
// Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
// your app will lose access to your Firestore database
match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if true;
}
```

Any help will be greatly helpful.

Comment: Firestore Security Rules has a dependency on the service account and IAM binding. If the firebaserules.system role is missing for the service account, your security rules will deny all requests.you can refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/iam#security_rule_dependency_on_iam) to set IAM role for the service account.

Comment: thanks, issues resolved

Comment: To better reuse the information which may help the GCP community. Please help to up vote the answer I added, Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

resolved using cloud console:

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding project name
--member=serviceAccount:service-project id@firebase-rules.iam.gserviceaccount.com 
--role=roles/firebaserules.system

Answer (score 3):

Firestore Security Rules has a dependency on the service account and IAM binding. If the firebaserules.system role is missing for the service account, your security rules will deny all requests.you can refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/iam#security_rule_dependency_on_iam) to set IAM role for the service account.